# Turnoff a certain warning in VSCode

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

[image]

Is there a way to turn off the unused var warning in all of the files React files in Vs Code. ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This probably has to do with linting, Maybe this can help you [no-unused-vars](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unused-vars)

You can also disable linting on one line

```
// eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
const [edit, setEdit] = useState({...})
```